# JavaScript can put an ansi string in a text field, but not utf-8?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, codepages

I always use UTF-8 everywhere. But I just stumbled upon a strange issue.

Here's a minimal example html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function Foo()
{
    var eacute_utf8 = "\xC3\xA9";
    var eacute_ansi = "\xE9";
    document.getElementById("bla1").value = eacute_utf8;
    document.getElementById("bla2").value = eacute_ansi;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="Foo()">
<input type="text" id="bla1">
<input type="text" id="bla2">
</body>
</html>
```

The html contains a utf-8 charset header, thus the page uses utf-8 encoding. Hence I would expect the first field to contain an 'é' (e acute) character, and the second field something like '�', as a single E9 byte is not a valid utf-8 encoded string.

However, to my surprise, the first contains 'Ã©' (as if the utf-8 data is interpreted as some ansi variant, probably iso-8859-1 or windows-1252), and the second contains the actual 'é' char. Why is this!?

Note that my problem is not related to the particular encoding that my text editor uses - this is exactly why I used the explicit \x character constructions. They contain the correct, binary representation (in ascii compatible notation) of this character in ansi and utf-8 encoding.

Suppose I would want to insert a 'ę' character, that's unicode U+0119, or 0xC4 0x99 in utf-8 encoding, and does not exist in iso-8859-1 or windows-1252 or latin1. How would that even be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript strings are always strings of Unicode characters, never bytes. Encoding headers or meta tags do not affect the interpretation of escape sequences. The `\x` escapes do not specify bytes but are shorthand for individual Unicode characters. Therefore the behavior is expected. `\xC3` is equivalent to `\u00C3`.

Comment: I realize that encoding headers or metatags have nothing to do with how JavaScript interprets literal strings or escape sequences. But I'd assume by enforcing a certain sequence to be inserted in the HTML field, then that is displayed according to the specified html ecoding. Anyway, as I understand it now, \x *always* refer to unicode codepoints (rather than bytes), and never ansi, right?

Comment: The character encoding specified only has meaning while that specific HTML file is being parsed by the browser and being turned into a DOM tree. All modern browsers store string data as Unicode internally.

Comment: Yes, in JavaScript, `\x` always refers to a Unicode codepoint. Remember though that the first 255 Unicode codepoints happen to match with ISO-8859-1 (latin-1) which was pretty popular in the day, so you might find that many characters will also match with whatever "ANSI" is.